# Deserialize my JSOn and bind to list in C# UWP

Tags: c#, json, parsing, uwp, json-deserialization

My Service returns a JSON like below, I want to Parse this and bind category_name to my list, how to do this in C#, UWP apps.

Iam trying to Deserialize this in this way

```
var content_resp = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            content_resp = "{ \"root\": " + content_resp.Trim().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}') + " }";
            var xmlProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(content_resp);

            var xmlProductNodes = xmlProducts.DescendantNodes();

            foreach (XElement xmlProduct in xmlProductNodes)
            {
                Places pl = new Places();
                var node = xmlProducts.Element("category_parent").Value;

                    pl.category_name = xmlProducts.Element("category_name").Value;                                                         
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //throw or return an appropriate response/exception
        }
```

when the debuger comes at this line

```
var xmlProducts = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(content_resp);
```

it is giving an error like 
"This operation would create an incorrectly structured document."

Comment: Is there a reason that you are converting JSON to an Xml structure here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way that I have found is to use Newtonsoft.Json
Firstly you should create class with data equal to your JSON:

```
public class AppsData
{
    private string _category_id;
    private string _category_name;

    public string category_id
    {
        get { return _category_id; }
        set { _category_id = value; }
    }

    public string category_name
    {
        get { return _category_name; }
        set { _category_name = value; }
    }
}
```

Then you can create some helper class:

```
    static class JSONhelper
{

    public static IList<T> DeserializeToList<T>(string jsonString)
    {
        var array = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(jsonString);

        IList<T> objectsList = new List<T>();

        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            try
            {
                objectsList.Add(item.ToObject<T>());       
            }
            catch { }    
        }
        return objectsList;
    }
}
```

Then create instance of List

```
IList<AppsData> appsdata;
```

and try to deserialize:

```
 appsdata = JSONhelper.DeserializeToList<AppsData>(stringWithJSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no reason to deserialize to XML you can do the following:

Create the class to parse

```
public class Product
{
    public string category_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("0")]
    public string Zero { get; set; }
    public string category_name { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("1")]
    public string One { get; set; }
    public string category_details { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2")]
    public string Two { get; set; }
    public string category_link { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3")]
    public string Three { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Product>>(your json);
```